# How to use localisation with image asset in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, localization

I need to localize my image in image asset folder in the xcode. Can anybody  help me out to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

Add 2 image sets to your Asset Catalog, one in English and one in Dutch, and postfix the name with the language code:

```
myImage-en
myImage-nl
```

Create string table entries (Localizable.strings) for each language as follows:

English file:

```
"myImage" = "myImage-en"
```

Dutch file:

```
"myImage" = "myImage-nl"
```

Now in your code you can use

```
let image = UIImage(named: NSLocalizedString(“myImage", comment:”language independent imageID"))
```

The iOS Localisation will now convert the language independent imageID “myImage” into a language specific imageID that is well known in the Asset Catalog.

I wrote a [blog post](http://peterfennema.nl/how-to-localise-images-using-asset-catalogs/) about exactly this topic.

Comment: I prefer this way of localization, not only for images but also for strings etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Qordoba SDK](https://www.qordoba.com/for_mobile) to manage the localization of the images, layout and strings.